# I have configured my Flink Application using PyFlink, but I want to change the Job Name

Tags: amazon-kinesis, pyflink, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I have configured Amazon Kinesis Data Analytic using PyFlink, but I want to change the Job Name to whatever I want. How can I do this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The job name could be specified via config option `pipeline.name`.